Does Entra Kerberos (Azure AD Kerberos) support sign in to file shares without line of sight to on-premises domain controller?
I was naively thinking that Azure Kerberos (Entra Kerberos or Cloud Kerberos Trust) can help me in the following hypothetical situation, but it seems to me that it won't (at least in its current state):

I have a hybrid-joined Windows 11 laptop, I'm signed in as a hybrid user synced with AD Connect.
From that laptop I have a network access to a network share \\hello.domain.com\share\ (domain joined).
But the laptop is out-of-office and doesn't have VPN into my company's LAN where AD DS domain controller is located. But it has network access to \\hello.domain.com\share\.
I want to access the network share using Kerberos authentication.

So am I right, that Azure Kerberos won't help me in this scenario?
My current less naive understanding is that Azure Kerberos just lets an Azure AD-joined computer to discover the on-premises domain controller and receive the Kerberos TGT from it, so line of sight with domain controller is a prerequisite for accessing any AD resources in this case. Right?
Blog post series about Azure Kerberos (Cloud Kerberos Trust) that helped me understand that Azure Kerberos won't help me (most likely): https://msendpointmgr.com/2023/03/04/cloud-kerberos-trust-part-1/

You need a connection to the Domain Controller.
Azure AD simply stores copies of AD users so users can sign in to the cloud using the same credentials.
See This link
